# Format the fields in the formulas

Tags: formatting, formula

It will not allow you to format the fields in the formulas. Simply {mb.mb-num}& "-" &{ln.ln-num} provides 1000.00-10.00 numbers, but I need the .00 removed from both numbers. I have tried everything suggested in the book and in previous posts and nothing... Help?

```
{mb.mb-num}& "-" &{ln.ln-num}
Totext({mb.mb-num}& "-" &{ln.ln-num})
Totext({mb.mb-num})& "-" &Totext({ln.ln-num})
```

Comment: This is in Crystal Reports...